# Displaying Custom Content On Different Pages All Using The Same Template

Tags: php, wordpress

This is my first Wordpress build so bear with me whilst I try to explain the issue.

I'm building a site for a hotel. 3 of the pages of the site all feature the same content (a heading, a paragraph of text and a gallery) and all feature a 'box', the content of which differs slightly from page to page. For example, on the 'accommodation' page the box will simply have paragraph text in, but on the 'restaurant' page the box will have links to downloadable PDF menus.

I've built a custom template file for these pages called 'standard-page'. My question is, what would be the best way to tackle this box issue? I'm guessing there is an easier way than creating a separate template for every page? The box does need to be content editable, so for each page the backend fields will differ (the restaurant page will require a file upload facility for example).

I've been following a Treehouse tutorial so far, but this isn't really covered in it. I've been using Custom Fields if that helps.

The only idea I can think of is having the box as a separate file (e.g. content-box) and having a WP_Query which calculates and displays different fields based on the page.

Here is an example of the different style boxes. The one with the offer is for the homepage.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

using a `content-box.php` would probably be your best bet and inside it - target the pages by name.

inside of the content-box.php:

```
 <?php if(is_page('accommodation')) {//show accommodation box}?>
 <?php elseif(is_page('restaurant')) {//show restaurant box }?>
```

etc.

Comment: How would I then edit these in the backend? Have a different custom post type for each box?

Comment: just create a new page with that name - for example 'accommodation'

Comment: Yes I understand each box will belong to a different page, but the boxes need to be editable from the admin, with different fields for each one (for example the middle box will need a field for the main title (New Website Offer), a field for the offer (15%).

Comment: Create a page called 'accommodation' inside of it put the content that you want to show in the box. - if you want to put content in the box via the backend create a [shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)